# Genesys Interaction Designer Subroutine

Tags: subroutine, genesys

I have created subroutine to trigger stored procedure.
It's published and appearing in Interactive Administrator Handler.
But this subroutine is not triggering. I have tried to use debug handler from Interaction Designer Utilities. At Call time, it is not triggering.

Answer (score 0):

After Creating Subroutine, we have to use subroutine initiator to route it.
Following link is useful:

https://help.genesys.com/cic/mergedProjects/wh_iat/desktop/modify_customsubroutineinitiatorrouter_ihd.htm